# Return dictionary from udf in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a function that gets a data frame that looks like that :

[image]

I want to return a dictionary with users and the tweets of each user.
This is the function :

[image]

How can I return a dictionary from the udf?

My code returns a function type.

Comment: Please post your dataframe and code in text, not as images.

Comment: as @mck said please include src data and code in text format and also paste the data type of column that is produced after using the UDF or error faced.

Comment: Yes please, I can see that you are a new contributor so please use the ` symbol to post your code.